# Trying to use px.scatter_mapbox with custom rgb / hex colors

Tags: plotly, plotly-express

I have a dataframe with each row being a geographical point with columns 'lat' 'lon' and others.
For each column, I create a map of all the point colored by that feature.

I do it with the following code:

````
    fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df, lat="lat", lon="lon", hover_name=hover_name, hover_data=hover_data,
                            color=feat,
                            color_continuous_scale=color_continuous_scale,
                            color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map,
                            range_color=range_color,
                            opacity=0.5, zoom=18)```
````

I want to use UMAP (from the library umap-learn) to reduce some number of features to 3, and from those new features, to create RGB colors that will be used as a color on the map.
I mapped the new umap 3d features to hex colors, added those as strings as a new column named 'color' and then I do the following:

```
    fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df, lat="lat", lon="lon", hover_name=hover_name, hover_data=hover_data,
                            color='color',
                            color_continuous_scale=None,
                            color_discrete_map='identitiy,
                            range_color=None,
                            opacity=0.5, zoom=18)
```

The problem is that when I do anything more than around 2000 rows, it won't load anywhere, it gets stuck. I save it as an html and try to open it, I also did fig.show() (it's default is the browswer) and it gets stuck, etc. When I do df.sample(frac = 0.05) it barely loads but eventually succeeds. What can I do to make it better?